# Swift - regex to remove "\\text { and_whatever_is_here }" from string

Tags: swift, regex, string, latex, expression

**Swift 5**

I am calling an API that returns a string containing LaTex elements. In a perfect world, a lot of the unneeded content would be removed by the API but it is returned and I need to remove it all manually.

Does anybody know how I could implement the following using one or more regular expressions?

---

`\\text { c. } 50 \\times 14`

Changed to:

`50 \\times 14`

---

`\\text { d. } 180 \\div 5`

Changed to:

`180 \\div 5`

---

A more complicated string:

`\\left. \\begin{array} { l l } { \\text { b) } 2 \\frac { 1 } { 5 } \\div ( \\frac { 4 } { 5 } - \\frac { 1 } { 4 } ) } & { } \\\\ { \\text { b) } \\frac { 1 } { 4 } - \\frac { 3 } { 4 } ) } & { } \\end{array} \\right.`

Changed to:

`\\left. \\begin{array} { l l } { 2 \\frac { 1 } { 5 } \\div ( \\frac { 4 } { 5 } - \\frac { 1 } { 4 } ) } & { } \\\\ { \\frac { 1 } { 4 } - \\frac { 3 } { 4 } ) } & { } \\end{array} \\right.`

---

Essentially I'm trying to remove any occurences of:

`\\text {`*and_this_also*`}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```swift
let text = #"\\left. \\begin{array} { l l } { \\text { b) } 2 \\frac { 1 } { 5 } \\div ( \\frac { 4 } { 5 } - \\frac { 1 } { 4 } ) } & { } \\\\ { \\text { b) } \\frac { 1 } { 4 } - \\frac { 3 } { 4 } ) } & { } \\end{array} \\right."#
let result = text.replacingOccurrences(of: #"\\\\text\s*\{[^{}]*\}"#, with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
\\left. \\begin{array} { l l } { 2 \\frac { 1 } { 5 } \\div ( \\frac { 4 } { 5 } - \\frac { 1 } { 4 } ) } & { } \\\\ { \\frac { 1 } { 4 } - \\frac { 3 } { 4 } ) } & { } \\end{array} \\right.
```

The `\\\\text\s*\{[^{}]*\}` pattern matches

- `\\\\text` - `\\text` string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\{` - a `{` char
- `[^{}]*` - zero or more chars other than `{` and `}`
- `\}` - a `}` char.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xNmrdy/1).

Comment: Thank-you Wiktor, out of interest why do you add `#` onto the string elements here?

Comment: @cook To avoid adding  backslashes to escape backslashes.

Comment: OK because it seems the regular expression above doesn't catch anything if the string to be formatted is a variable from something external, rather than something hard-coded at the time of doing the replacement.

Comment: @cook That is not clear. Do you have `let str = "\\text { c. } 50 \\times 14"`, or `let str = #"\\text { c. } 50 \\times 14"#`? I understood that the text you posted in the question is a plain text, as if it is a text inside Notepad++ open document.

Comment: I mentioned that I am calling an API that returns a string containing LaTex elements, so at this point I wouldn't know what exactly would return but the ones I posted were some that I've come across. Sorry I could have been clearer, but essentially those strings I posted are some scenarios I've seen but there will definitely be different cases each time the API is called. One thing that stays constant however is that the strings mostly always return with "\\text { something }" in them, of which I need to remove.

Comment: How did you obtain the "strings"? You say "I've come across", "some scenarios I've seen", **where**? In the console, in the text file that you saved these texts in?

Comment: I have tried the below in response to your solution above and it still returns the original string unfortunately.
`let toFormat = #"\#(item)"#`
`let result = toFormat.replacingOccurrences(of: #"\\\\text\s*\{[^{}]*\}"#, with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)`

Comment: If you copied these texts from the console, you have single slashes, and then you need ``text.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\\\text\\s*\\{[^{}]*\\}", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)``

Comment: Yes, in the console while debugging I have seen the responses from the API.

Comment: Why `let toFormat = #"\#(item)"#`? Just use `item.replacingOccurrences(...`